# Ctrl + Shift + U not working in MS Office 2007 under Wine

Tags: wine, shortcut-keys, microsoft-office

I have to deal with this problem on another family PC on which I forced Linux installation over Windows.

I'm well aware that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Number doesn't work on Linux, that's why I was relying on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> combo, which works absolutely fine in Libre Office. If that won't be solved, I will be probably forced to install Windows back.

Using Libre Office is no option in this case...